# Repair + Naming question

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So heres the problem.

I need to repair my enchanted pickaxe, and it is renamed too. This makes me tryint to repair it via another unenchanted pickaxe impossible (its too expensive)

If i reset my name to default, will that make the cost of repairing my pickaxe much cheaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No.

The way the repair costs work is that every time you use the item in an anvil the prior work penalty (stored in the `RepairCost` data tag) is increased depending on the current `RepairCost` values of both items.

Renaming an item does not change the prior work penalty.

Once an item gets too expensive to repair, there is nothing you can do but make a new one. The Mending enchantment allows you to repair items with XP rather than the anvil, allowing you to keep the item indefinitely.